# Will webpack with babel es2015 preset fix closure issues on IE 11?

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, webpack-2

If I write a for loop using the `let` keyword to declare my loop variable, and I pass that variable to a

```js
for(let x=0;x<5;x++){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(x);},1000);
}
```

call, it will not work in IE 11 because IE 11 does not support ES2015. But I can write this code in Typescript, compile, and use Babel to output to supposedly IE11-compatible code. Will Babel successfully recognize and fix this?

I realize this is relatively simple to test myself once I get an environment all set up but I kinda feel like this might just be the tip of the iceberg for what Babel can and cannot do. Just wondering if someone knows off the top of their head if or how this works and if there are some related closure-related things that Babel just cannot transform. Thanks in advance.
---Edit---
Passing the variable 'x' into the function actually yields an undefined error so I guess I was breaking some other rule there. But, after removing the anonymous function parameter to create a proper closure on 'x', I find that the Babel conversion does NOT properly log the value 0,1,2,3... At this point I guess I would disagree with those who are saying that it does properly convert this scenario. Or I am totally missing something. (Thanks to the first person who replied with the link to babeljs.io/repl ! Very cool.)

Comment: You don't have to set up an environment to find this out. You can put your code in question right into the Babel REPL: https://babeljs.io/repl/. I would do it for you, but you haven't shown us the actual code you're talking about.

Comment: [Yes.](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=GYewTgBAFANgpgFwgDwgXggBgNwogHggEYcUBqMgSggG8AoCCAZ0QBUBLAWzhAFcEoUamgB8EAMYgAdkxDwAdDBABzKMkoAaYph2VsdAL5A&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3%2Ces2015-loose&targets=&version=6.26.0)

Comment: Mike definitely deserves credit for answering this. See his comment below. Thanks again, Mike.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using `env` aka es2015 preset.

in `babelrc`:

```
{
   "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: Thanks. I used JLRishe's suggestion above and went to babeljs.io/repl to test the code. The conversion runs in IE 11 but yields different results. Original ES2015 code yields 0,1,2,3,4,5 while the converted code yields 6,6,6,6,6,6

Comment: @Wade Even though I think it's obvious, I just tried the generated code - see Mike C's linked example -  in IE 11 - and it works. Since the `_loop` function captures `x` that is as expected.

Comment: Did you try the code that uses 'let' on, say, Chrome which is ES2015 compatible? Did you get the same output that the converted code gives on IE11? That's the issue that I am driving at. I see different output and I fear that the Babel translation is just superficial text replacement, not true behavior replacement.

Comment: @Wade Yes, I ran the code as is on Chrome and got the correct output. I also ran the Babel output on IE11 and got the correct output. Babel is not doing artificial text replacement. You can see that it correctly generates a function to keep the scope rules imposed by `let`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. It made me go back and check my original code and I saw what I did wrong. I was passing x into the anonymous function and getting undefined on both the ES and the ported function because...well...both were invalid lol. After properly making a closure by removing the function parameter, and reconverting with Babel, it did do Magic! Wow, I am impressed. Thanks, Mike. Now post your answer as an full-blown answer so you can get paid!